# How to create a numpy tensor

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, tensor

I'm a student learning ML with Python. I got a task from my teacher to create a numpy tensor consisting of:

- 100 samples
- 64 timesteps
- 32 height
- 16 width
- 3 channels

This is what I tried:

```
import numpy as np
my_tensor = np.array(100, 64, 32, 16, 3)
```

And this:

```
import numpy as np
my_tensor = np.array
my_tensor.reshape(100, 64, 32, 16, 3)
```

Please, help me! I don't understand this terminology (samples, timesteps, etc.). Please, explain this and tell me what I am doing wrong. How do I create such a tensor?

Comment: Your teacher to asked you a tensor representing a `video`. `samples` means how many videos you have. `timestamp` is the same as the time bar in youtube. `width` and `height` are pixels representing width and height, and `3` represents `RGB` channel i.r. Red, Green, Blue

Comment: one trivial creation method is `np.random.rand(100, 64, 32, 16, 3)` - a tensor of the shape you desire filled with (uniform) random values between 0, 1

Comment: I suggest spending some time on [Numpy quickstart](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#numpy-quickstart) or if you are completely new the [Numpy begginers guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#numpy-the-absolute-basics-for-beginners). It will pay off :)